# Nautilus-Actions only show context option for file not folder

Tags: nautilus-actions

I'm using nautilus-actions to run scripts and commands by right clicking in nautilus and I know how to set nautilus-actions so that it only shows an option when certain conditions are met, such as mime-type, part of a name or a particular file extension.

I still haven't figured out how to show these options for any file, but not folders. I'm sure this option exists, but I just can't seem to find it. Does anyone know how to do that? if there is a graphical option, could you provide a screenshot of it, so I can try to localize it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself, although I wasn't counting on it to work.

On Ubuntu folders have the 'mimetype' `inode/directory`, so filtering on this mimetype in nautilus-actions actually works.