# Nautilus - no support for hard links?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions, nautilus-script, hard-link

I finally got round to [studying and understanding hard links](http://blog.programster.org/hard-soft-links/) in my quest to check I have understood the basics, of which I have managed to skip a lot of. After realizing how brilliant they are, I wonder why there isn't better support for them in Ubuntu's default file manager, nautilus.

At the moment, there is only one option for creating a link to a file, and it will create a "soft" link.

[image]

The trouble with this is that they break as soon as you move or rename the original file.

### Question

Is there a way to get nautilus to create a hard link, or some sort of addon/script/configuration/tweak I can do to add the option in the right-click menu, or a keyboard shortcut, to create a hard link for a file?

Comment: Hard links can be make using the `ln` command in `terminal`. But the question might be asked... why do you want/need hard links vs soft links? Do you understand the disk space ramifications of each?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently this option is intentionally cut years ago. From the topic [Creating hard links](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317268) from bugzilla.gnome.org:

> Almost none of our users knows the hardlink concept, so why should we
> confuse him and even risk data loss? You can use
> nautilus-open-terminal and create hardlinks manually.

---

The good news is you have two options to create this feature:

- by using Nautilus Actions or
- by using Nautilus Scripts

### Solution 1: by using Nautilus Actions

**1.** First install the package [`nautilus-actions`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nautilus-actions):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nautilus-actions
```

Or use Ubuntu Software:

[image: install nautilus-actions]

**2.** Run the program:

[image: run nautilus-actions]

**3.** Go to 'Preferences' and uncheck 'Create root Nautilus Action menu':

[image: nautilus-actions Preferences]

When this option is ticked, in the context menu will have sub menu, etc.

**4.** Click on **Define new action** button and fill the data in the **Action** tab. As *Context Label* you can use `Make Hard Link`, also tick only the option `Display item in selection context menu` - in other words display this item when a file is selected.

[image: Define new action - Action]

**5.** Go to **Command** tab and fill the parameters:

- *Profile*:
- *Label*: `Default profile` - if there is no any custom profile.
- *Command*:
- *Path*: `/bin/ln` - this is path to the executable file (or command).
- *Parameters*: `%f "Hard Link to "%b""` - click on Legend button for more info.
- *Working directory*: `%d` - means current directory.

[image: Define new action - Command]

**6.** Because [Directory hardlinks break the filesystem in multiple ways](https://askubuntu.com/a/525129/566421) we must disable this possibility. Go to **Mimetypes** tab and add a [new rule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571759/nautilus-actions-only-show-context-option-for-file-not-folder):

- *Mimetype filter*: `inode/directory`,
- with `Must not match any of` option selected.

[image: Define new action - Mimetypes]

**7.** **Record** the action **Make Hard Link**:

[image: Define new action - Record]

**8.** Run Nautilus and use **Make Hard Link** action from the context menu:

[image]

---

Additionally, if you want to backup your settings:

- the file `$HOME/.config/nautilus-actions/nautilus-actions.conf` contains Nautilus Actions preferences.
- and the new actions are places within the folder: `$HOME/.local/share/file-manager/actions/`.

### Solution 2: by using Nautilus Scripts

The same result can be achieved via a script, placed into `$HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`. This script could looks like:

```bash
$ cat "$HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Make Hard Link"

#!/bin/bash
if [[ -f "$1" ]]
then
        ln "$1" "Hard Link to $1"
fi
```

We can create this script and give to it executable permissions via the command:

```bash
ScriptNAME="$HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Make Hard Link" && \
printf '#!/bin/bash\nif [[ -f \"$1\" ]]\nthen\n\tln \"$1\" \"Hard Link to $1\"\nfi\n' |\
tee "$ScriptNAME" && chmod +x "$ScriptNAME"
```

The result will be:

[image]

References:

- [How to get Nautilus-scripts working Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281062/how-to-get-nautilus-scripts-working-nautilus)
- [How do I customize the context menu in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus)
- [Check if passed argument is file or directory in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665051/check-if-passed-argument-is-file-or-directory-in-bash)

Comment: Hey, it works. It feels weird to have to perform a bunch of GUI based steps. Now that I have that set up, can I just copy/overwrite some config file in future?

Comment: Hay @Programster, we can use `find` command in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33407344/6543935) way: `find $HOME -mmin -360 | grep action` - to find all files, within the user's home directory, that are changed last 6 hours and whose names contains the string 'action'. I will update the answer tomorrow, I think we do not need 'Nautilus Actions' at all. Maybe just a `.desktop` file, placed into `$HOME/.local/share/file-manager/actions/` will be enough.

Comment: @Programster, I've updated the answer with another approach.

Comment: Thanks - just a suggestion to move the script approach to the top - I almost missed it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MikeMcKay. I've made some edits :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the answer very useful.

A slightly improved version of the script:  -> [ ln "$1" "$(dirname $1)/Hard Link to $(basename $1)" ] - It works also when clicking within a file in a expanded tree.

Comment: Hi, @CarlosRuiz, you are welcome to update the answer with your improved solution.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the answers here I wrote a Nautilus/Nemo script that makes hard links from multiple file selection.

```
#!/bin/bash
# make hard links for multiple file selection
# be careful of not moving the hard link to a different file system
HARDLINK_ICON=${HOME}/.local/share/icons/mine/folder-green-activities-icon.png
for arg 
do
    # make a hard link of the selected file
    if [[ -f "$arg" ]] 
    then
        HARDLINK_NAME="Hard Link to $arg"
        ln "$arg" "${HARDLINK_NAME}"
        gio set -t string "${HARDLINK_NAME}" metadata::custom-icon file:///${HARDLINK_ICON}
    fi
done
```

1. Make sure of adding your icons to your local home folder. Something like `${HOME}/.local/share/icons/mine/folder-green-activities-icon.png`
2. Be mindful of not moving the hard link to a different file system; it will not work. If the icon doesn't show, it is most likely that cut-and-pasted the hard link to a different file system.

Comment: Thanks.  This change makes the script work too with files in an expanded tree [         HARDLINK_NAME="$(dirname $arg)/Hard Link to $(basename $arg)" ]

Comment: This makes it work with expanded tree and file name with spaces in them:
HARDLINK_NAME="$(dirname "$arg")/Hard Link to $(basename "$arg")"